# Attempting to iterate with ruby thru 4 twitter bootstrap columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I am attempting to iterate over a post object, and displaying its body attribute in 4 columns, as to behave like so:

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class=’row’>
    <div class='col-lg-3'><%= *post.body* %></div>
    <div class='col-lg-3'><%= *post.body* %></div>
    <div class='col-lg-3'><%= *post.body* %></div>
    <div class='col-lg-3'><%= *post.body* %></div>
  </div>
  <div class=’row’>
    <div class='col-lg-3'><%= *post.body* %></div>
    <div class='col-lg-3'><%= *post.body* %></div>
    <div class='col-lg-3'><%= *post.body* %></div>
    <div class='col-lg-3'><%= *post.body* %></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried the following:

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
  <% @posts.each_slice(4) do |four_posts| %>
    <div class="row">
      <% four_posts.each do |post| %>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <%= post.body %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
     </div>
   <% end %>
 </div>
```

The issue I'm having is that the 'body' content is running in to the adjoining column.  Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of what the page currently looks like?

Comment: also, you used `|post|` twice, I would not recommend that to avoid confusion. You should change the first `|post|` to `|four_posts|` or something similar.

Comment: okay.  thanks David.  First time posting.  I am trying to find a way to edit the post as to attach a screenshot ...

Comment: Believe link to screenshot successfully added .. my apologies on the delay ...

Comment: Maybe it's better to use `col-md-3` instead of `col-lg-3`?

Comment: @jmcgillion what's the generated source html?

Comment: I am looking at, and it seems like the html, looks correct in that it says ...:<div class='col-lg-3'> content </div> , etc ... perhaps, i should look a bit harder :-) ..

Comment: Alex, I did try that, but I believe is more geared to what device you are on, laptop etc ..

Comment: https://codepen.io/leoj3n/pen/bkDHA don't see any problem. maybe you should check along the lines of custom overwriting css or import failures? the only change i added was another container so that the two rows doesnt overflow into one another.

Comment: Okay,  I was thinking perhaps I should look in to matters to that end.  And yes, the advisement is much appreciated ...